# Rotate Text orientation on Canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas in my Angular application where user can play around with the coordinates of some fixed shapes(8 texts and 1 rectangle). I want to be able to be able to allow user to also select the orientation of the text i.e. show horizontal or vertical. How can I achieve this behaviour. Appreciate any help.

```
redrawLabel(result: ISerialLabelDesign) {
    console.log('inside redrawLabel');
    this.clearDrawing();
    this.shapesToDrawArray.length = 0;
    console.log(result); // giving the entire form.value object
    this.defaultLabelWidth = 300//result.labelWidth * 3.7795;  // convert from mm to pixel
    this.defaultLabelHeight = 300//result.labelHeight * 3.7795;
    this.renderDrawing(result);
    this.startDrawing(this.shapesToDrawArray);
}

startDrawing(shapesToDraw: Shape[]) {
    console.log('inside startDrawing::');
    for (var i = 0; i < shapesToDraw.length; i++) {
        if (shapesToDraw[i].type === 'barcode') {
            this.drawRectangle(this.context, shapesToDraw[i].x, shapesToDraw[i].y, shapesToDraw[i].w, shapesToDraw[i].h);
        } else if (shapesToDraw[i].type === 'text') {
            this.drawText(this.context, shapesToDraw[i].text, shapesToDraw[i].x, shapesToDraw[i].y, shapesToDraw[i].w, shapesToDraw[i].h);
        }
    }
}

private drawRectangle(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number) {
    console.log('inside drawRectangle');
    context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
}

private drawText(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, text: string, x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number) {
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.font = '8px Arial';
    context.fillText(text, x, y);
}
```

[image]

Comment: The red text in your screenshot is not vertical text (a.k.a top-to-bottom), it's left-to-right, with a weird alignment, and rotated. Vertical text would Have all the letters in the usual orientation but following a vertical direction. So "A" would be on top of "d", and at the left of *Name*'s "N". Which one do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rotate your text with `rotate()` as followed:

```
private drawText(context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, text: string, x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number) {
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.font = '8px Arial';
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 2); // Rotation of the text
    context.textBaseline = 'middle';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillText(text, x, y);
}
```

Comment: thanks but did not work on the fly

Comment: Yes, you need to render your canvas again

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the HTML5 Canvas, we can use the rotate() transform method.  The rotate transformation requires an angle in radians.  To define the rotation point, we need to first translate the canvas context such that the top left corner of the context lies on the desired rotation point.
use css :
Transform : rotate(90deg)

Comment: Thanks but I dont need to rotate the canvas only the text orientation.